# AvaloniaUI - MVVM/ReactiveUI - compatability with standard ReactiveUI

Tags: reactiveui, avaloniaui, message-bus

Avalonia UI has an own implementation/version of ReactiveUI. How compatible is this library with the standard ReactiveUI library ?

In other words, can I create my models and viewmodels in a standard library with the nuget for the standard ReactiveUI library (not the avalonia one) and leave it up to the clients how to implement the UI/views ? If they prefer WPF, Xamarin, UNO or Maui (all possible with ReactiveUI at this moment), they can use one of these for the views. If they prefer avalonia for the views, they can use the Avalonia implementation. Is that possible ?

A second question is if the Avalonia-ReactiveUI messagebus is 100% compatible with regular ReactiveUI (for the same reason as mentioned before) ? So can I pass messages from regular/standard ReactiveUI to a AvaloniaUI-ReactiveUI implementation ?

Comment: Members of the RxUI team are also active members of Avalonia so we have a reasonable relationship with Avalonia. Disclaimer i am a maintainer of RxUI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avalonia is using standard ReactiveUI since 0.6.0. Avalonia.ReactiveUI package just configures the required services.